# $f(x,y)=(x+y,x^2+y^2)$ is this function globally $1-1$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U=\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ x>y \}$  and $f: U\to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by, $$f(x,y)=(x+y,x^2+y^2)$$. Then whether $f$ is globally one-one or not?

If we calculate its derivative matrix then we will get, 
$$ Df(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1\\ 2x & 2y \end{pmatrix}, $$ the determinant of this matrix is $2y-2x\neq 0, \forall\ (x,y)\in U$. So can I conclude that $f$ is globally $1-1$ on $U$?

Comment: Even simpler, for any $i,j\in\mathbb{R}$, setting $f(x,y)=(i,j)$ gives the intersection of a line and a circle.  This has at most two points, but at most one of them will have $x>y$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x,y)=(a,b)$ then $a^2-b=2xy$ and so $x$ and $y$ are the roots
of $$t^2-at+\frac{a^2-b}2=0.$$
Thus $x$ is the larger, and $y$ the smaller root.

Comment: $x$ is a root of $t^2-at+\frac{a^2-b}2=0$ but  why $  x^2-ax+xy= 0$

Comment: Because $a^2-b = 2xy$.

Answer (score 0):

If it is one-one then we will have that $$f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$$will give us that $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$.
Now, consider the numbers $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(y_1,x_1)$ where $x_1,y_1 \in \mathbb{R}/${$x\in \mathbb{R}:x\le0\} and x_1\ne y_1.$Then we have$$f(x_1,y_1)=f(y_1,x_1)$$ but, $(x_1,y_1)\ne(y_1,x_1)$ and hence $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$. Thus, the function is not one-one globally.

Consider for example $(1,2)\&(2,1)$ here, $$f(1,2)= (3,5)$$ & $$f(2,1)= (3,5)$$ and thus not one-one.